# How to access "internal" modifier class properties from external assembly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

At the outset, let me say that I have seen a sort of solution for the problem, but I found this this is majorly used for testing purpose only.

Could anyone give me a good practice way of calling a internal class's internal static property from the external assembly in C#?

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a small example in C#. I am aware of using "AssemblyVisibleTo" but I was told that it is not a good way to code.

Comment: This whole question is not a good idea.  However, if you need to do it, `[InternalsVisibleTo]` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: The only "good practice" is not to do it.  The property was likely made `internal` for a reason and does not expect external code to modify it.

Comment: Isn't the entire idea behind the `internal` keyword to prevent `external` assembly from accessing it?

Comment: The real question is _why_ do you need to access the internal static data?  If it's for unit testing look into Dependency Injection.

Comment: @shf301 unit testing is a reasonable reason to expose internals to another assembly.  I've never found the "just don't test that" hand waving terribly satisfactory.

Comment: If you are aware that using `AssemblyVisibleTo` is not a good way to code, how can you suppose other way of doing the same thing will be better? Do not call internal entities from other assembly because they are internal because of something. If you believe it should not be internal, make it public.

Comment: @48klocs: I disagree.  Why should unit tests see the internals of an assembly?  Tests should validate the externally-visible behavior, not the internal implementation.  If the tests are dependent upon the internal implementation then the tests are tightly coupled to that specific implementation, reducing the value and portability of the tests.

Comment: Guys, you all are real .NET folks and I am a newbie, I do not understand anything of what you people speak :( My client told me, this approach of using assembly line is not in favor of most internet articles.

Comment: @Divine To avoid this question becoming an minor XY Problem, can you explain why you want to use internal items?

Comment: @David I suppose we'll have to agree to disagree; there are implementation details that I don't want callers to be aware of (trying to build an API that leads people down the happy path) while at the same time, I want to be able to equal parts test and mock away details of my implementation so I can test small units independently of one another.

Comment: @shf301: Sorry that didn't made any sense, because you understood my question wrong. I am not into modifying. It contains all error codes and values (Display Messages). Automatically its implemented to use it. However, at one scenario, I want to call that error code elsewhere.

Comment: @Divine `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` or reflection are your only options, people are just getting hung up on the "good practice" bit, because none of it would be considered good practice, it's only a compromise.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Thank you, its already existing 10,000 line codes of more than 100 files and large number of projects. I am new to this and I told, this is not a good way to implement it when I use the attribute you just gave. Please help me :(

Comment: @Divine That attribute or reflection are about equivalent. What was the reason given to you why it wasn't a good way to do it? Sounds like someone providing advice without any real information to back it up. I'd also like to know how they are proposing to solve the problem.

Comment: @David: Also, if the tests are only looking at externally visible behavior they are no longer unit tests, but rather are functional tests.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: uhmm Well I will see if there are any other ways to do it, like hwo its implemented in my project and surely if I get a result, I will post here. I don't know really though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to access `internal` data (whether static or not):

1. **Reflection** - this defeats the purpose of keeping the data `internal` as you now have external code that is directly dependent on the internal implementation
2. **`InternalsVisibleTo` Attribute** - you have been told that this is "not a good way to code", which most would agree with, however you were not given an alternative (hence your question).  This has bacically the same drawbacks as reflection (it just makes the client code cleaner).
3. **Add a public-facing API** - if this data is useful *outside the assembly* then perhaps the best solution is to add a public API on top of it!  You can still hide the internal mechanisms, which allows you to change the internal guts, so long as the *external* interface remains intact.

So propose those three alternatives to your client and see which they prefer.

Comment: Hi Mr Stanley, thank you so much for your advise, it helps me a lot. I will take it to him and see what he has to say. We already have a robust way of doing it, its a very robust and challening code (According to me), so I am unable to understand how its implemented in other places. I can feel and see it. But I do not know how to follow the same pattern (Maybe because of which he told its not good way that I did by using InternalVisibleTo attribute. Anyway, I need to propose a solution tomorrow :( So sad of me lol :( I will try :) Thank you again for your help. :)